# Why is chrome so fast?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

I was reading [this](http://carlos.bueno.org/2010/02/measuring-javascript-parse-and-load.html?v=2) article and Chrome seems to be way ahead of the pack. But why is it so good? It's only been around for about a year but it's much better than any of the others.

Can anyone shed any technical light on this?

Comment: May be because you don't have much tabs open - chrome is slower compared to FF if there are around 10-15 tabs open at a time - for me at least.

Comment: I disagree. On my 13" laptop, Chrome can easily handle 15-20 tabs. As I am typing, I have 16 tabs open and it doesn't seem to be performing any slower than when it was first opened. Maybe this has something to do with the way these tabs are architected. Unlike most other browsers, Chrome creates a new process for each tab.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"We've often been asked what makes Google Chrome so fast -- from its snappy start-up time and fast page-loading, to the ability to run complex web applications quickly. To walk through some of the thought processes and technical decisions involved in making Google Chrome a fast browser, we've put together three technical interviews on DNS pre-resolution, the V8 JavaScript engine, and DOM bindings. In a future post, we'll also cover other important areas like WebKit and UI responsiveness."  via http://blog.chromium.org/2009/12/technically-speaking-what-makes-google.html

Answer (score 4):

"It's only been around for a year", and that's the point.  It's brand new and shiney, uncluttered with legacy code, outmoded assumptions and general bloatware.  It's pretty slim on actual features too.  Also, google have had an awful lot of money and motivation to throw around recently, compared to the impovirished mozilla, and the tired old guardians of IE.